# Ratio for home work

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In the year 2000 a rich aunty won £12000 and decided to share her money between her 3 nieces in the ratio of their age 14 10 18. she died in 2006 how much will each niece get?

Comment: What have you done? Is this homework?

Answer (score 1):

If their ages at $2000,$ are $14,10,18$ years respectively,

their ages at $2006,$ will be  $14+6,10+6,18+6$ or $20,16,24$ years respectively.

The ratio of ages in $2006,$ will be $5:4:6$

So, the eldest will get $\frac{6}{5+4+6}\cdot 12000£=\frac{2\cdot 12000}5£=4800£$

and the youngest will have $\frac{4}{5+4+6}\cdot 12000£=\frac{4\cdot 12000}{15}£=3200£$

and the middle one will have $\frac{5}{5+4+6}\cdot 12000£=\frac{\cdot 12000}3£=4000£$

Answer (score 0):

If the women shared the money in 2000 when she earned them this should be :
14+10+18=42.

You have :
  14 ........... 42
  x  ........... 12000

x=14*12000/42= £4000 for the first one

10 ........... 42
  y  ........... 12000

y=10*12000/42= £2857,14 for the second one

18 ........... 42
  z  ........... 12000

z=10*12000/42= £5142,85 for the third one

If the money was shared in 2006 when she died, you have to do same calculus, but with this data: 20 , 16 , 24;

20+16+24=60

So , the first one will get 4000, the second one 3200, and the third one 4800.